# How to get data from database based on current element while ng-repeating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring

I am building spring webapp and I have a `div` table and want to display some data from an array in angularjs's `$scope` using `ng-repeat`. Something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements>
{{element.id}}
</div>
```

What I want is to get some additional data about current `element` stored in another table in database, so something like this:

```
...
{{getImage(element.id)}}
...
```

I am using rest approach to get data from database, so I send get http request and store data in `$scope`.

Something like this don't work:

```
$scope.getImage = function(id){

            $http.get("services/rest/getImage/" + id).then(function(response){
                return response.data;
            },
            function(response){

            });

        }
```

It just starts an infinite loop of sending http requests, and I think it has to do something with asynchronous javascript requests, as I want to get an element from database and assign it to something else at the same time.

So how should I resolve this?

Comment: why wont you load the related data in first api call?

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything....and it can't because the request is asynchronous. Don't put functions in view that make asynchronous calls unless they are doing something that reacts to a user event

Comment: @charlietfl Should I make then another java class, and load data from multiple tables and use that, or there is another approach?

Comment: Simplest is loop through `elements` array in controller or service and request each image before sending to view. Of course adding it to original api call as a property is most efficient

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a directive to get images inside ng-repeat and set it to `img` tag. i am assuming your are returning image URL or base64 format data from your HTTP call also during ng-repeat id will be available in scope so in below code i am using `scope.id` to get `id`:

```
angular.module('app').directive('imageSetter',[function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
           $http.get("services/rest/getImage/" + scope.id).then(function(response){
                attrs.$set('src', response.data);
            },
            function(response){
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Usage: `<img src="" image-setter>`